# jQuery add and remove textbox Add all Previews textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my jQuery add and remove textbox task, I just want to add my previous all textbox on Add Button. So if I will click first time it will add only 1 and if I will click again it will add 2nd textbox and if I will click again it will add 3rd textbox for me. I want just count the counter variable and then add +2 textbox in it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var counter = 2;

  $("#addButton").click(function() {

    if (counter > 10) {
      alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
      return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
  });

  $("#removeButton").click(function() {
    if (counter == 1) {
      alert("No more textbox to remove");
      return false;
    }

    counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

  });

  $("#getButtonValue").click(function() {

    var msg = '';
    for (i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
    }
    alert(msg);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>jQuery add / remove textbox example</h1>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
  <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1'>
  </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
```

Comment: Not sure - do you want to add 1 or 2 or 3 boxes in one go or add 1, then another 1 and then another 1?

Comment: could you explain correctly the behaviour you want to achieve

Comment: can you please explain ?

Comment: When I click it will add 1 total =2

Comment: When I click on Add button it will add 1 total = 2, If I will click another time the total will be = 4, I need to add 2 textbox every time.

Comment: @Ginni see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you want the number of input in creation to be always even number .

so simple just check the `$("#TextBoxesGroup input").length % 2` wether it's 0 or 1 and create inputs using loop , (this last will create one or input at same time )

See below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var counter = 2;

  $("#addButton").click(function() {

    if (counter > 10) {
      alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
      return false;
    }
    
    var num_to_create = 0;
    $("#TextBoxesGroup input").length%2 === 0 ? num_to_create = 2 : num_to_create = 1;
    
    
    for(var inc=0 ; inc < num_to_create; inc++) {
      var newTextBoxDiv = $('<div>')
        .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

      newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
        '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
        '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

      newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
      
      counter++;
      
    }
    


    
  });

  $("#removeButton").click(function() {
    if (counter == 1) {
      alert("No more textbox to remove");
      return false;
    }

    counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

  });

  $("#getButtonValue").click(function() {

    var msg = '';
    for (i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
    }
    alert(msg);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>jQuery add / remove textbox example</h1>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
  <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1'>
  </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
```

Comment: @Ginni , helpfull ?

Comment: Thankyou very much.